# Logging inside a Flask microservice

Tags: python, logging, flask

I created a `Flask` app. All `Flask` code is inside `api.py`.  This app uses other files, for example `utils.py`. This file contains functions that will be used from the `api.py`.

Inside `api.py` I am using `app.logger` for logging, like

```
app.logger.debug('HI')
```

This log is displayed in the console.

but in `utils.py` I am using:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('utils')

...

logger.debug('SOME MESSAGE')
```

But nothing is displayed in the console.

One awful, *awful*, **Awful** hack that I am using now, is importing `app` from `api.py`

```
from . import api

api.app.logger.debug('SOME MESSAGE')
```

And this message is displayed in the console. But I know that I am wrongdoing here. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask uses the global app object to store this stuff. What you most likely want to do is

```
from flask import current_app

current_app.logger.debug('hi')
```

Alternatively, you could configure the default logger to log to a file the same way that flask configures *its* logger to do so using standard python logging methods.

```
# app_logger.py
import logging
import logging.config


logging.config.fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

Then in other files...

```
#utils.py
from app_logger import logger
logger.debug('hi')
```

This second way is how I set up logging for my flask apps, create a global "logger" object and import that object everywhere I want to log (allowing me to easily figure out where to change the config to do things like log to stdout or a file or whatever)

Comment: Could you give an example of the last advice? Which method do *you* recommend?

Comment: Actually, this first one is not working, it throws the following error: `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Comment: Yes, you would only be able to hit the logger for current_app while actually serving requests.

Comment: Mmmmm. So the *only* way to get logging into the console is with your second  proposed approach, right? Could you point me to an example of that?

Comment: Well, not quite- you just have to make sure you don't call that logger outside of a request (and just about everything in flask happens inside a request). Like I said though, I do prefer to use my own logging, I added an edit.